# Disable specific time from timepicker UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, timepicker

I would like to disable times between 12pm and 12.30pm on my mvc razorview javascript

```
        $('#timepicker').timepicker({
            interval: 3,
            minTime: '9:00am',
            maxTime: '4:00pm',
            scrollbar: true,
            dropdown: true,
            zindex: 10000,
            startTime: '9:00am'
        });
```

Comment: You can refer to [jquery.timepicker](https://www.jonthornton.com/jquery-timepicker/) and scroll to `DisableTimeRanges Example`

Comment: @LamTranDuc still not working, not sure if am using a wrong library?

Comment: Can you use another library? The link I sent you earlier is another library with the feature you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel-9 jQuery Timepicker Disable specific time how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75874362/laravel-9-jquery-timepicker-disable-specific-time-how)